# Sharepoint 2013 Web API Order By ListItemAllFields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using a SP 2013 document library to back a ASP.NET MVC web application. I can only use web api to access the doc library.  What I am trying to do is use OData to do some filtering and sorting on some custom columns I added to the doc library. The way to access those is to expand on ListItemAllFields. When I try to $orderby or $filter one of those nested properties I get an error.

My get call looks like this:

```
https://<site>/sites/iro/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestDocs')/rootfolder/folders('TestFolder')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields&$orderby=ListItemAllFields/CustomColumn
```

The response from SP though is a 400 and is as follows:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Field or property \"CustomColumn\" does not exist."
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using items at the document library level which returns all the columns as a flat object but the items call doesn't work at the folder level. Since I only want to access the documents within specific folders this is a requirement.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the files in *perticular folder* by below REST call.

```
http:<site>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Backup Library/Filtered')/Files
```

Where

- *Backup Library* is name of my library
- *Filtered* is folder under the library

Url is tested and works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but not what I am looking for. I am looking to filter on custom column metadata. Unless you're proposing manually filtering files by metadata into separate folders which I don't think would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that we can sort using orderby in case of ListItemAllFields. I created a custom sort function, which sorts the result after executing the query. Update the function accordingly.

```
// prop => property to sort by
// arr => input array format - [{ListItemAllFields:{FieldValuesAsText:{Title : 'ABC', ID : 1, ...}, ...}, ...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
var sortC = function (prop, arr) {
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText[prop] < b.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText[prop]) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText[prop] > b.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText[prop]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return arr
};
```